# JQuery SlideUp - Background Color Behind Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery slideUp/slideDown to add an overlay to an image that is hidden until mouseover and then slides up from the bottom of the image.

The div that is sliding up is given a background color, but it doesn't show up over the image, it shows up behind it (the text shows up on top of the image, but I can just see the bottom edge of the div's background color because of the margins I set). Z-index is already set to 100.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

$(".slider").attr("style", "display: none;");

if ($(".slider")) {
  $('.image').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find(".slider").slideDown("400");
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find(".slider").slideUp("400");
  });
}
    
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.image{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #000000;
}
.slider {
  background-color: #333333 !important;
  background: #333333 !important;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: -90px 0 0 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">

  </div>

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your jQuery selector is incorrect. You should use `$(this).parent().find(".slider").slideDown("400");` instead, because there is no `.slider` inside of `$(this)` container, which is in this case `.image`. But then if you hover over the slider, it would go away. I'm not sure if it's the desired behavior... Probably it's better to bind the `mouseover`/`mouseout` events to the container instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to define `display: none;` for slider in css rule.
Also to bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to `container` will prevent jumping `slider` when mouse is leaving image and moving over slider.

```js
$('.container').on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".slider").slideDown();
  });
  $('.container').on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(".slider").slideUp("400");
  });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.image{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #000000;
}
.slider {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: -90px 0 0 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, Banzay. This along with Marco's suggestion to make the position relative did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

If you do not define position, element will be static, as that's default position for block elements.

M.

Comment: Thanks Marko. This helped get the background to show up above the image.